# Como pegar o índice de um objeto javascript buscando pelo valor?

Tags: javascript, objetos, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho um objeto JS assim(valores fictícios):

```
{
aifuw    :    7,
hsjwo    :    5,
hsgqk    :    137,
jskwe    :    9483,
NNNNN... :    N...
}
```

Eu preciso pegar o índice onde o valor seja *137*.
As formas que tentei não deram certo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa iterar todas as propriedades do objeto (exceto as herdadas), até achar o valor da que você quer:

```
function chavePorValor(obj, val) {
    for(var chave in obj) {
        if(obj[chave] === val && obj.hasOwnProperty(chave)) {
            return chave;
        }
    }
}

var dados = {
    aifuw    :    7,
    hsjwo    :    5,
    hsgqk    :    137,
    jskwe    :    9483
};
chavePorValor(dados, 137); // hsgqk
```

Nota: se houver mais de uma chave com o mesmo valor, a função retornará a primeira que encontrar (geralmente a primeira a ter sido declarada no objeto, mas o JavaScript não garante a ordem das chaves do objeto).

Answer (score 3):

Você pode iterar nas propriedades assim: suponha que seu objeto se chame `obj` então você pode fazer

```
for(prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if (obj[prop] === 137) {
            indice = prop;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Basicamente, `for (prop in obj)` é um loop for que itera em todas as propriedades do objeto sendo que `prop` é uma string com o nome da propriedade atual no loop. A verificação do `if` serve pra verificar se a propriedade é realmente do objeto e não do protótipo. Se for do objeto então verifica-se se o valor é `137` (seu exemplo) seta-se o índice e sai do loop.

Isso ainda tem um problema, você pode ter várias propriedades com aquele valor, então faz mais sentido retornar todas (o código acima só retorna a primeira), nesse caso teria que tirar o break. Basicamente, isso faz mais sentido em uma função, por exemplo:

```
function encontraPropriedadesComValor(objeto, valor) {
    var nomesPropriedades = [];
    for(prop in objeto) {
        if (objeto.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (objeto[prop] === valor) {
                nomesPropriedades.push(prop);
            }
        }

    }
    return nomesPropriedades;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Veja se é isso que você procura.

```
var objeto = 
{
  aifuw : 7,
  hsjwo : 5,
  hsgqk : 137,
  ahayh : 137,
  jskwe : 9483,
}

function procurarporChave(obj, value)
{
    return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) 
    {
      return obj[key] == value;
    })
}

var valor = '137';

chaves = procurarporChave(objeto, valor);
alert(chaves); // hsgqk, ahayh
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sLQdU/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Se você for usar a biblioteca underscore

sugiro fazer dessa forma.

```
   _.each({
   aifuw    :    7,
   hsjwo    :    5,
   hsgqk    :    137,
   jskwe    :    9483,
   NNNNN... :    N...
   }, function(element, key) { element == 137 ? alert(key) : "" });
```

[jsfile](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZqSw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Outra possibilidade seria com (mais uma) solução proposta pelo pessoal do [PHPJS](https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/functions/array/array_search.js) baseada no [array_search()](http://www.php.net/array_search) do PHP:

```
function array_search(needle, haystack, argStrict) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/array_search/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  //    input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  //  depends on: array
  //        test: skip
  //   example 1: array_search('zonneveld', {firstname: 'kevin', middle: 'van', surname: 'zonneveld'});
  //   returns 1: 'surname'
  //   example 2: ini_set('phpjs.return_phpjs_arrays', 'on');
  //   example 2: var ordered_arr = array({3:'value'}, {2:'value'}, {'a':'value'}, {'b':'value'});
  //   example 2: var key = array_search(/val/g, ordered_arr); // or var key = ordered_arr.search(/val/g);
  //   returns 2: '3'

  var strict = !! argStrict,
    key = '';

  if (haystack && typeof haystack === 'object' && haystack.change_key_case) { // Duck-type check for our own array()-created PHPJS_Array
    return haystack.search(needle, argStrict);
  }
  if (typeof needle === 'object' && needle.exec) { // Duck-type for RegExp
    if (!strict) { // Let's consider case sensitive searches as strict
      var flags = 'i' + (needle.global ? 'g' : '') +
        (needle.multiline ? 'm' : '') +
        (needle.sticky ? 'y' : ''); // sticky is FF only
      needle = new RegExp(needle.source, flags);
    }
    for (key in haystack) {
      if (needle.test(haystack[key])) {
        return key;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  for (key in haystack) {
    if ((strict && haystack[key] === needle) || (!strict && haystack[key] == needle)) {
      return key;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

[Demonstração](http://jsfiddle.net/brunoaugusto/79AGM/1) no JSFiddle.

Segue a mesma idéia das outras respostas, no entanto, por se tratar de um *port* de um recurso de outra linguagem, inclui um recurso adicional que pode vir a calhar.