# Como pegar os índices de um json com javascript?

Tags: javascript

**Por exemplo:**

```
var carro = {
    "modelo": "celta",
    "ano": 2007
}
```

Como eu posso fazer uma função genérica que retorne os nomes dos índices desse json, no caso, "modelo" e "ano"?

Algo como:

```
function(json){
       //faz o processo
      return indices;
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicidade!
As questões a seguir devem resolver o problema proposto.

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17765/como-pegar-o-%c3%adndice-de-um-objeto-javascript-buscando-pelo-valor?rq=1

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86839/como-filtrar-dados-de-um-json-com-js?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var carro = {
    "modelo": "celta",
    "ano": 2007
}
var chaves = Object.keys(carro);
alert(JSON.stringify(chaves));
```

Existe o `Object.keys(meuObjeto);` que faz exatamente isso.